# Blending with Quartz 2D 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, quartz-2d

[image: TableViewCell]

The above is a UITableViewCell containing two UILabels. The cell has a transparent background using [UIColor clearColor] and the background pattern (*you may need to look closely to see it*) is set on the UITableView using UIColor's initWithPatternImage.

What I'd like to be able to do is blend the text with the background pattern so that the text has the texture coming through. The only thing is I'm not sure of is the best way of achieving this.

I know I can use NSString instead of UILabels and draw the text directly into an image, but can this then be blended with the background even though it's not being drawn in the same drawRect (*i.e. the text image would be drawn in a subclass of UITableViewCell where as the background is being drawn by the UITableView instance*)?

The other way is to create an image mask from the text, have another image which is already textured (*with the top half white and the bottom half dark grey*) and then use that to draw the text, as outlined [in this Cocoa with Love tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/09/creating-alpha-masks-from-text-on.html).

Whilst I can obviously use the tutorial to achieve the second implementation, I'm more inclined to explore the first as it'd use no external images and may be more efficient.

Your thoughts, links and code examples will be greatly appreciated.

***Please Note: Setting a low alpha value on the UILabels does not achieve the desired effect***

Comment: What's the problem with setting the alpha?

Comment: It doesn't achieve the desired effect. Lowering the alpha value also lowers the intensity of the colour. I'm looking to maintain the intensity whilst applying the feel of the underlying texture.

Comment: The effect is very subtle. Have you tried playing with the alpha, and making the color of the letters lighter (i.e. more "white") to compensate? Alternatively, you can use your own "pattern-color" for the letters, although this would probably be hard to line up with the rest.

Comment: The image above is already using the technique you're referring to. The top UILabel for instance has the colour `[UIColor whiteColor]` but has an alpha level of .75 which is why it appears darker (*therefore I can't make the actual colour any brighter*). There is a difference between making something *see through* which is this technique, and blending with the underlying texture which is what I'm looking to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the labels as non opaque and an alpha value less than 1.0 it should work. These can be set in either Interface Builder or as code like this:

```
[theIncidentLabel setOpaque:NO];
[theIncidentLabel setAlpha:0.5];
```

You can even just set the text color to a color with an alpha value less than 1.0.

```
[theIncidentLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5]];
```

Using these settings I do see the background texture through labels in a project I'm working on. In my project the list UITableView is also transparent, and the background texture comes from an image loaded in a UIImageView behind the UITableView.

This is simple alpha blending. We figured out through a discussion in comments that this is inadequate for your needs. Instead you can use the alpha masking as explained in the tutorial mentioned.

Alternatively, you could forgo alpha masks and just draw the text to a CGImage, then draw that image on your background pattern with a different blend mode, maybe kCGBlendModeScreen. Here's the drawRect method from the above mentioned tutorial rewritten with this technique:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        // Draw a black background
    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

        // Draw the text upside-down
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, rect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    [[UIColor lightGrayColor] setFill];
    [text drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:40.0]];
        // Draw it again in a darker color.
    [[UIColor darkGrayColor] setFill];
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, 50.0);
    [text drawInRect:rect withFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:40.0]];
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        // Create an text image from what we've drawn so far
    CGImageRef textImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

        // Draw a white background (overwriting the previous work)
    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

        // Draw the background image
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    [[UIImage imageNamed:@"shuttle.jpg"] drawInRect:rect];
        // Set the blend mode. Try different options to meet your tastes.
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeScreen);
        // Draw the text.
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, textImage);
        // Clean up.
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    CGImageRelease(textImage);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid, as I noted above, this does not achieve the desired effect. The labels above are all non-opaque and all have an alpha value of .75 yet as you can clearly see the texture is not coming through.

Comment: .75 alpha is still very opaque. I opened your above image in Photoshop, and examined the values in the initial "T". Where they should be one value they vary from 27% to 29%. This is very subtle, but it is showing a very small amount of the background pattern through the characters.

Comment: I definitely think clipping masks may be the way to go rather than using just relying on the alpha value; the lower the alpha value, the harder it'll be to identify the letters, and it's not really achieving the effect I'm looking for.

Comment: I concur. Alpha blending is working, it's just not giving the visual results you'd like.

Comment: Are you able to provide any insight (*code perhaps?*) to achieve what I want beyond what the linked tutorial does?

Comment: You could get close to your intended look by using the tutorial's drawRect code, except change the initial background color to white, the lighter text to darkGrayColor, and the darker text to lightGrayColor when drawing the alpha mask. Or you could forgo alpha masks and just draw the text to an offscreen CGImage, then draw that image on your background pattern with a different blend mode, maybe kCGBlendModeScreen. (See CGContextSetBlendMode and CGContextDrawImage.)

Comment: I'm intrigued by your second suggestion. If you'd care to provide a working implementation demonstrating that it achieves the desired effect I'd be happy to accept it as the answer (*provided you post it as a separate answer*)

Comment: I updated my previous answer with a blending mode based variation of the tutorial code. I did not post a second answer because a second answer seems to be counter to this site's founders' intentions. According to Jeff and Joel on the Stack Exchange podcast, Stack Exchange sites work better when answers are edited and improved instead of leaving an inadequate answer and adding a second different answer.

Comment: No worries; I'll give this a try later on today and post back with how I got on.

Comment: Also, since I mentioned above that the background isn't drawn in the cell but in the tableview, will this code still work? i.e. just remove this line `[[UIImage imageNamed:@"shuttle.jpg"] drawInRect:rect];`

Comment: I'm tested this and I'm afraid it doesn't work. Did you test it before posting?

Comment: Yes, I tested it. It works for me by just replacing this one function in the project downloaded from the tutorial. CG blend modes do not work beyond the current context, i.e. with other views below the view you are drawing to. Therefore you must put the background in on this layer. If you can't include the background pattern in the table cell view, you are limited to alpha blending.

Comment: Ah, I tried adjusting the method above to fit my project which is probably why it didn't work. But, based on what you've just stated clipping may be the only way I'm going to be able to achieve what I'm looking for then.